# Core Data Tools Version increase - Should I also increase the model version?

Tags: ios, xcode, core-data, core-data-migration

My CoreData model currently uses old (Xcode 3.2) format. I'd like to increase it to the latest one available, in which data is represented in the XML form:

[image: cd version]

**Should I also increase the Model Version Number** in the Core Data editor?

[image: model version]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I cannot think of any reason why you'd need to do that as *Model Version* and *Tools Version* should be unrelated and orthogonal.

I have a 10-year old Mac app, Core Data document, which I've always built with the latest Xcode but I never bothered to change the *Tools Version* in its one data model, which contains 28 entities and a lot of relationships.  Until 30 minutes ago, its *Tools Version* was *Xcode 3.2*, like yours.  To prove my point, I changed only the *Tools Version*, to *Automatic (Xcode 9.0)*, did a *Clean Build Folder*, then test, build and run.  It passed my test suite, launched fine, opens documents, saves changes.  No trouble found.  Everything works fine.  I plan to commit this change and ship my next version with it.